# Using collection with filter return model objects

Tags: laravel-5, collections

In my laravel 5.7 I use collection with filter, but I would liek to return not integer value I set to this filter, but 
model objects on filtered values, like :

```
$selectedSubscriptions = collect($tempSelectedSubscriptions)->filter(function ($item) {
    $nextTempSelectedSubscription = SiteSubscription::find($item);
    if ($nextTempSelectedSubscription !== null) {
        return (object)['id' => $nextTempSelectedSubscription->id, 'name' => $nextTempSelectedSubscription->name];
    }
});
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: I assume `tempSelectedSubscriptions` is an array of `SiteSubscription` ids, so can you not just use `SiteSubscription::findMany($tempSelectedSubscriptions);` to get a collection of all `SiteSubscriptions` in `$tempSelectedSubscriptions`?

Comment: Thank you your feedback, as here filter is rather simple, but for most complicated cases if filter method(or some other method) if array of models/classes can be returned ?

Comment: You can only return a boolean in the `filter` method that determines if the item is kept or not. You could use [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map) instead, it will iterate through each item in the collection and you are free to return whatever you want and create a new collection from the returned values.